# WebRTC Works on Every Browser Except on FireFox how?

Tags: reactjs, webrtc

I have a VideoCall based app it works in Chrome And Opera GX but when Ii try to Run it in the Firefox it change the state of the connection to failed

```
const createOffer = async () => {
  try {
    const sdp = await pc.current.createOffer({ offerToReceiveAudio: true, offerToReceiveVideo: true });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(sdp));
    pc.current.setLocalDescription(sdp);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating offer:", error);
  }
};

const createAnswer = async () => {
  try {
    const sdp = await pc.current.createAnswer({ offerToReceiveAudio: true, offerToReceiveVideo: true });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(sdp));
    pc.current.setLocalDescription(sdp);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating answer:", error);
  }
};

const setRemoteDescription = () => {
  const sdp = JSON.parse(inputRef.current.value);
  console.log(sdp);
  pc.current.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(sdp));
};

const addIceCandidate = () => {
  const candidate = JSON.parse(inputRef.current.value);
  pc.current.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
};
```

Those are the functions I use to handle my SDP and ICE.  How can I solve it?

I tried to Enable RTC from Firefox configure but it still does not work and I get the same error